# Copying char array and sort

Tags: c, arrays, char

**Aim:** to save the latest 5 dates from a very large bank of dates without storing all dates. This will be run on an Arduino style microcontroller, but thought it is more relevant to the C language in general.

My current method is to copy the 6 digit char array of the date (yymmdd) into the last position of a 6 date array, sort from latest to earliest, then iterate over the whole bank of dates.

Here is the complete working code:

```
int compareDates(const void *a, const void *b) 
{ 
    const char **ia = (const char **)a;
    const char **ib = (const char **)b;
    return -strcmp(*ia, *ib);
} 

int main(){

    char *latestDates[] = {"200418","991201","020718","050607","121030","000000"};
    size_t len = sizeof(latestDates) / sizeof(char *);

    char newDate[][7] = {"071122","150101"};
    size_t numNewDates = sizeof(newDate)/sizeof(newDate[0]);

    for(uint i=0; i<numNewDates; i++){

        latestDates[5] = (char*)malloc(7);
        strcpy( latestDates[5], newDate[i] );

        cout << "Before sort: " << i << endl;
        for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
        {
          cout << latestDates[i] << endl;
        }

        qsort(latestDates, len, sizeof(char *), compareDates);

        cout << "After sort: " << i << endl;
        for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
        {
          cout << latestDates[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    free(latestDates[5]);

    return 0;
}
```

The code can also be run/edit here: [cpp.sh/3rl7y3](http://cpp.sh/3rl7y3)

**The question is:** how to take the dependency on pointers and malloc out? i.e. initialise `latestDates[6][7]` instead of `*latestDates[]`.

Comment: Which language? Remove the faulty tag, please. Also, your code needs to be inline in the question, not behind a link to some external site who's content may change. Further, consider extracting a [mcve] first. As a reminder, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: There is no multiple dimensional array in your code, that's part of the problem. strncpy is another problem.

Comment: You have an array of pointers, if that's what you really want then you are going to have to allocate some memory for the pointers to point to before you try and copy any strings. And don't use `strncpy`, despite its name it doesn't copy strings. Use `strcpy` instead.

Comment: @PhD_Dan Select one language tag either C or C++.

Comment: For C++, use `std::string`, `std::vector`, and `std::sort`.

Comment: Thanks, your comments have been noted for next time!

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code that keeps the array of pointers

```
char *latestDates[] = {"200418","991201","020718","050607","121030","000000"};
char newDate[] = "551122";

latestDates[5] = malloc(strlen(newDate) + 1);
strcpy(latestDates[5], newDate);
```

I'm not claiming it's good code or anything, but it's legal.

Comment: Thanks John, `(char*)malloc(7)` works. And I will `free(latestDates[5])` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (if there is no need to be a pointer)

```
char latestDates[][7] = {"200418","991201","020718","050607","121030","000000"};
```